# Cannot use MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have been following a tutorial to use Node.js, Express, Jade and MongoDB together. I have been having some trouble using the database, starting with when I try to access information from it in Jade, but now I am at the point where I cannot even access it via command prompt.

Whenever I navigate to the installed location (C:/mongo/bin) and enter the command:

> mongo

I get back:

```
MongoDB shell version 2.6.5
connecting to: test
Warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Could anyone please help me figure out how to use MongoDB again on my computer? It worked once before when I installed it. Note, I am using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongo` is just the shell cli to interact with the mongo server.
As far as i know you still need to start mongo server first.

Check in the explorer what other files are in the bin directory. there should be a `mongod.exe` file. When you open it a command line should open. As long as this is open, the server is running and you should be able to interact with it through the `mongo` command.

Comment: as far as I know, I think I am starting it before hand but I get then error message as described in my question in command prompt

Comment: Is there a mongod.exe file in the bin folder?

Comment: open up mongo.exe and leave the cmd running. Have a look at my answer again, i edited it and added that part.

Comment: Yes it works, I can access the database through command prompt and view the data I put in a few days ago! Now I'm just trying to get it to work with node.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64443/discussion-between-jnk-and-bs7280).

Answer (score 2):

> mongo.exe opens an mongodb client, you need to run mongod.exe first to open mongodb server then in another shell run `mongo` command again.

Elaborating a bit on this answer - there are two different commands you need to execute, and you need to do them in order:

- `mongod` - this command is executed to start up your MongoDB server. This makes everything on the actual server available, including your database instances that are stored there.
- `mongo` - this command is executed to start up the Mongo shell. The Mongo shell allows you to interact with the databases and collections, and depends on the databases and collections being available (i.e. the server needs to be running).